# Cassandra Replication in NetworkTopologyStrategy

Tags: cassandra, database-replication

I've just started learning about Cassandra. I have a doubt in NetworkTopologyStrategy. So as we know the nodes in Cassandra is divided based on the hash value of the partition keys. If so during a write operation with replication factor 3, the data is written in a total of 3 nodes.

1st in the node that falls under the hash key value. And the next two replicas is written in different Rack of the same Datacenter. Will this 2nd node has the same hash value index or will they have different.

If different, won't the data is written in another hash value index?

Pls provide some clarification on this..

Answer (score 2):

All the copies will have the same hash value. Cassandra will use those hash values to compute binary hash trees, named Merkle trees, which are used by the repair to identify when they are discrepancies in the versions of the records.

If you are interested, there is an explanation of this process [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archAntiEntropyRepair.html#Howdoesanti-entropyrepairwork?).

Comment: But I don't know how the replicas are placed in NetworkTopologyStrategy having multiple DataCenter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a different question not included in the original post. The replicas in different datacenters will follow the `replication` directive of the keyspace. Please look at the bottom of https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateKeyspace.html which has an example of the use of 3 different datacenters

Answer (score 1):

The keyspace created with multiple DC's generally has the following structure:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cycling
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
   'datacenter1' : 3,
   'datacenter2' : 2 
  } 
AND DURABLE_WRITES = true ;
```

Note that the datacenter1 will have 3 replicas of row and 2 in datacenter2.
When data is written to Cassandra every DC will fulfill the replication factor as defined in the keyspace definition.

1. A write operation for the row will be done on the node which is responsible for the token for the given partition key. The replicas for that row will be written to two subsequent nodes in the cluster in a clockwise manner in the best case.
2. The same sequence is followed within the other DC, datacenter2 in this example but with only 2 copied of the row

> Will this 2nd node has the same hash value index or will they have different?

The assignment of partition to nodes is done based on the tokens generated by [partitioners](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archPartitionerAbout.html) and [Murmur3Partitioner](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archPartitionerAbout.htm) by default.